# SQL UPDATE table query taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update

SQL Server 2005, Win Server 2003 32-bit:

I have a table with tag names and number values. I'm trying to use the UPDATE command to fill in the number values of that table by matching tag names with another table on a specific day/time. For some reason it takes forever (more than 30 minutes) to execute.

```
DECLARE @Year INT;
DECLARE @JanDate Datetime
SET @Year = 2014;
SET @JanDate = CAST(
                CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(4)) + '03' +  '27'
                AS DATETIME)
UPDATE PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals
SET 
        Feb = [value]
FROM    runtime.dbo.History
WHERE   runtime.dbo.History.Tagname = PARCS_DB.dbo.tbl_Utilities_PARCS_Totals.Tagname2
AND     wwVersion = 'Latest'
AND     DateTime = @JanDate
```

IF I manually query the runtime database for values by tagname and date it comes up instantly.

Comment: It might be really quick to SELECT the data but the UPDATE will run a lot slower if there are many indexes and/or constraints to also update.

Comment: There is only 1 clustered and 1 non clustered index in the DB for the table I'm using UPDATE on. No constrains that I can see.

Comment: Also, even trying to cancel the query takes forever. Going on 1 hour just to cancel. I'm only looking up 5 values.

Comment: Try and refrag the database.

Comment: Show the table definitions and also the index defintions.

Comment: Also the number of rows might be useful.  If you have enough space you could try copying the data into a new table, add a single index to cover your query and see if you have the same performance woes?  Is this running in a transaction and what recovery model is your database running in?

Comment: Not sure how to view the definitions? It's 5 rows and 14 columns (the table I'm updating). The table has no indexes (I was wrong above). Recovery model is Simple. What do you mean by running in a transaction?

Comment: Any more ideas on this? Do I need to create an index?

Comment: still looking for some advice on this one. Thanks!